# Overriding a "dictionary" hosts var for ansible-playbook (yaml)

Tags: ansible

(I have checked and there are some similar questions on SO, but none seem to precisely answer my problem)

I have a playbook I use to build some Kubernetes stuff and I've been using single-level variables in my `hosts.yaml` like this:

```yaml
item1: value1
item2: value2
```

This is fine and works just fine, but since a lot of these are similar, I want to group them -- so for example I could then do:

```yaml
kubernetes:
  control_plane_version: 1.25.0
  node_version: 1.25.0
  ...
```

And herein comes the problem. Let me give you a very basic example:

`playbook.yaml`

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "Test value: {{debug.value}}"
```

`hosts.yaml`

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
  vars:
    debug:
      value: original_value
```

Running this will give you the expected value:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml playbook.yaml
...
TASK [Debug] ***********`**********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Test value: original_value"
}
```

Now lets override with another yaml:
`hosts2.yaml`

```yaml
debug:
  value: hosts2_value
```

And run the playbook again. Again we get the expected overridden value:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml playbook.yaml -e "@hosts2.yaml"
...
TASK [Debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Test value: hosts2_value"
}
```

But now comes the weirdness. According to the documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence), `-e` will always win, and that makes sense -- if I put the `hosts2.yaml` ahead of the `set`, the `set` value will win.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml playbook.yaml -e "@hosts2.yaml" -e '{"debug":{"value":"set_value"}}'
...
TASK [Debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Test value: set_value"
}
```

And if I put the set value before the `hosts2.yaml`, the `hosts2.yaml` value will win.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml playbook.yaml -e '{"debug":{"value":"set_value"}}' -e "@hosts2.yaml"
...
TASK [Debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Test value: hosts2_value"
}
```

The problem I have though, is how do I override the value using the cleaner yaml syntax. The example shown above shows I can do so using json syntax, but I'd rather be able to do this with yaml as it's far easier to read. [This section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables) in the documentation implies I can reference the value using dot or bracket syntax, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml playbook.yaml -e 'debug.value=set-value'
...
TASK [Debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Test value: original_value"
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I don't think you can, you're limited to json only: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#key-value-format

Comment: I don't like your -e form. It should be `var=value`. Try `-e "debug={{{"value":"set_value"}}}"` (note: tipple {{{ and }}} here).

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin thanks that appears to work, but why the triple `{{{ }}}`?

Comment: dict in jinja. `{{ }}` is a jinja expression, and `{"value":"set_value"}` is a dict. This way it forces ansible to do a proper type conversion.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeShuklini if you want the rep, post an answer and I'll accept it